# Simulating and verifying DDR3L clock

Tags: xilinx, signal-integrity, ddr3, zynq

## Context

I am working on a PCB that hosts a Zynq Ultrascale+ SoC and has 9 DDR3L SDRAMs (MT41K512M8DA) operating at 1866Mbps, and I have to verify the signal integrity of the DDR3L interface. I am using Ansys SIwave and Ansys Electronics Desktop to perform such simulations. I do not have much experience with either signal integrity simulations or DDR3L interfaces.

I have checked and the simulation has all the IBIS models corresponding to the SoC and the SDRAMs.

***NOTE**: Please let me know if further information is required, and I'll edit this.*

## Problem

The clock signal's waveform degrades as it propagates through the fly-by topology. I would like to understand two different aspects:

- Is there an eye diagram mask for the DDR3L clock signal so I can verify if it still complies with the JEDEC standard?
- Is this a normal behavior due to the amount of SDRAMs connected to the clock?

***NOTE**: Ignore the orange plot, I was comparing the signal's quality after making some improvements in the layout.*

### Clock Eye Diagram @ Zynq Ultrascale+

[image: Clock eye diagram at the Zyqn Ultrascale+ SoC]

### Clock Eye Diagram @ 9th SDRAM (last SDRAM before termination)

[image]

## What are my thoughts?

At first, I thought the layout had issues that were causing this behavior, considering I expected a more nicely shaped clock waveform. After trying various obvious layout changes and seeing only small improvements in the signal's quality, I decided to ask myself: what should I be seeing?

After that, I performed a simulation replacing the PCB's model and replaced it with ideal transmission lines, ignoring the effect of vias. The Zynq Ultrascale+ SoC connects to the first SDRAM with an ideal transmission line, then the first SDRAM connects to the second SDRAM with an ideal transmission line, and so on. I know it's very ideal... but it showed similar behavior.

By disconnecting SDRAMs, and reading the datasheet, I figured out that the responsible may be the input capacitance of the SDRAMs that's causing an impedance discontinuity and at this rise/fall time the reflections are pretty noticeable. But if I'm right, then this is a normal behavior. If an ideal simulation exhibits the same signal quality, then there's nothing I can do in the layout.